# How to triangulate a polygon without random inner points?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, computational-geometry

I would like to create triangles a predefined polygon. My requirement is that I don't want to create random points inside of this polygon for processing it with a Delaunay Triangulation algorithm.
The polygon can be concave or convex.

It's totally ok for me to use a Delaunay Triangulation but I don't want to create random points inside the polygon. It would be much nicer if I can create as less points as possible inside this polygon.
I would like to minimize the number of used triangles.

How can I establish this?

Comment: It's more a language agnostic thing, I like to know how to implement this on my own.

Comment: So you want to minimise the number of triangles required?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'm going to add this info.

Comment: I presume it isn't convex, triangulating a convex polygon sounds too simple.

Comment: It may vary: The polygon may be concave or convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the very helpfull library [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/). The Java branch of this library does exactly what I need.

I just need to use it correctly. It does not add any points to the polygon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Ear Clipping or monotone polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).  Neither algorithm will introduce extra points.

(If you choose to form monotone polygons, the monotone polygons are convex, and can be broken into triangle fans directly.)

Answer (score 0):

If the polygon is convex, it's easy to just use the boundary and triangulate using points along the boundary. If it's non-convex I would make a convex boundary, and mark the points inserted as inserted. Then, when done with everything else, remove the inserted points.

You can also use a mesh refinement algorithm to refine the mesh if you get long and thin triangles. Using Delaunay you can just check if a triangle is "thin" by some definition, and if it's "thin" insert a point in the circumcenter of that triangle. Thus all you then have to do is use Delaunay theory.

Comment: I think for concave polygons, it would change the outer shape, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, as you triangulate it as a convex, then remove the points outside of your original boundary. Of course, you will have to use all the points on the original boundary as well, and when you then remove the points outside the boundary the original boundary will be the new boundary, which have the same outer shape. At least I don't think it will change the outer shape.